# How to pass deviceToken from AppDelegate to ViewController? iam getting DeviceToken is nil

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm getting DeviceToken is `nil`
Please help me.

Code in AppDelegate is as follows

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    NSLog(@"Device token : %@", deviceToken);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceTokenString forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"isNotificationsEnabled"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Code of ViewDidLoad

```
- (IBAction)NextBtn:(id)sender
{

    NSString *getDeviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    NSLog(@"DeviceToken:%@",getDeviceToken);
    getDeviceToken = [getDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    getDeviceToken = [getDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    [service registerWithCounty:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)country1.Id] andPhoneNumber:self.phNumber andDeviceId:getDeviceToken];
}
```

Comment: You run your project on device. on simulator it get nil.

Comment: In simulator device token will be null, check in device

Comment: iam getting  error NSError * domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3000 0x14d0a9a0   in didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError plz help me

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone Simulator cannot receive push notifications or successfully register for them.
You should rather use a device for testing this functionality.

For registering and using PUSH functionality you require a APNS supported provisioning profile which can be utilised/installed on a device only.

Answer (score 0):

Register for `RemoteNotification` in following method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { }
```

with following `code`

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:
         [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
          (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                           categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
```

Then implement following `method`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString* strToken = [deviceToken description];
    strToken = [strToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    strToken = [strToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:strToken forKey:@"device_token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];       iam getting error like registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later